# Limit discount code to once per person

Tags: cognito-forms

I've created a referral discount code, I will personally hand out the discount code when someone refers someone else and that person orders. I Only want that person to be able to use that code once. (could be an unlimited # of people that could receive the code for referring someone) so I don't want to just limit the number of times the code can be used overall. Just limit an email to using the code once.

Answer (score 0):

Contacted cognito support to make sure it works on the live site, and i was told it does!

> create a calculation field with the below code

```
=if CouponCode.ToUpper = "THANKS123" then (Email + " " + CouponCode) else null
```

> set the calculation field to No duplicates in the settings

this limits a specific code to a one time use, while allowing all other codes to be used as many takes as you'd like.